# Force Stop occurs although build has no error ?

Tags: android

My program is not working well, and I don't understand why, mind helping out please?

```
    package project.ernest;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Part1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    Intent DisclaimerHandler = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part2.class);
    {
    Part1.this.startActivity(DisclaimerHandler);
   }
}
```

I have 2 .java file, namely, Part1 and Part2. 
as well as a .xml file name disclaimer placed under layout

I tried to run it, but it gave me a force stop.

Comment: would you mind pasting the stack trace in logcat????

Comment: what is the error you are getting in Logcat.

Comment: sorry i am new, Logcat, how do i navigate to there?

Comment: Window->Show View-> other's-> type Logcat

Comment: channel '406bbc70' is it this?

Comment: yup. i am still getting error, "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class{project.ernest/project.ernest.Part2};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this..

```
 package project.ernest;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Part1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

      final Button gs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save); 
      gs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Part2.class);         
            Part1.this.startActivity(i);    
        }
    });          
}
```

Comment: but it fail the moment i click on disclaimer

Comment: which is one of the buttons i've named.

Comment: but, when i click the button i define above, a message popup to forcestop

Comment: <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Part2"/>
   this is what i declared in the manifest file

Comment: <activity android:name=".Part2" android:label="@string/app_name"/> change like this.

Comment: then do you know why i am still getting an error? could it be because of the java file which i didnt code at the src/

Comment: yup. i am still getting error, "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class{project.ernest/project.ernest.Part2};

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="project.ernest"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Part1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       <activity android:name=".Part2" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
  </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".Part1" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity android:name=".Part2" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

Comment: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{project.ernest/project.ernest.Part2}

Comment: problem in manifest file . can u send the code i will modify it or edit at top of this question

Comment: I didnt create any code in Part2 btw. which is the java file.

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="project.ernest" android:versionCode="1" adroid:versionName="1.0"> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"> <activity android:name=".Part1" android:label="@string/app_name"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> </intent-filter> 
        </activity> <activity android:name=".Part2" android:label="@string/app_name"/> </application>
</manifest>

Comment: u have xml and Part2.java files in the project.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, DONE THIS PART THAT I NEED ALR LOVE YOU GUYS

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say anything without the logcat, but I'll try to guess. Probably you've forgot to declare your `Part2` activity in your Manifest file. Hope I'm right.

Comment: <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Part2"/>

Comment: @user990571, name should the full name including your package name, like com.google.android.SomeClass.

Comment: the package name is project.ernest

Comment: @user990571, then the full class name will be project.ernest.Part2

Comment: <activity android:name=".Part2" android:label="@string/app_name"/> its is .Part2 because i have placed it as . right?

Comment: @user990571, this will work if your Part2 is located in the root of your src folder

Comment: yup. i am still getting error, "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class{project.ernest/project.ernest.Part2};

Comment: @user990571, by the way, does the Part2 class extend activity?

Comment: package project.ernest;

public class Part2 {
}

Comment: @user990571, hey, you can't start an activity if your class does not extend activity! You better learn some before you start to code for Android, go to developer.android.com and read the articles!

Comment: the thing is, i dont know how to start the activity even when i read, mind helping me out bro?

Comment: @user990571, you need to read better. Sorry, I've no time to explain you something that's written in books and tutorials. Would be glad to answer some more specific questions from you.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, DONE THIS PART THAT I NEED ALR LOVE YOU GUYS

Comment: @user990571, Nice! You can express your love by accepting one of the answers here you've found most useful, and upvoting others, that were also useful to you. Good luck!